# Override Meta tag

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

I am using jQuery .load() to load some html files into my "master" page. The users who are creating the html files are using MS Word. I've noticed that MS Word inserts this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
```

Because I am loading the pages using .load(), there are some characters that do not get encoded correctly and little boxes show in their place.

Can I override that meta tag inside the html files created in MS Word? If not that, what would be my best way to get the characters be interpreted correctly when I load the html pages? I know I can use MS Word, open the file and save as a filtered web page which fixes the issue, but there are a couple thousand links and I'd like to find a different way.

In my index.html page, I have this meta tag character set defined, which I tried changing to match the one created by MS Word, which did not work.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Example:

// Get the url of the MS Word created file I want to load into my html page.

```
var url = "\somepath\somepage.htm";
```

// Use the load method of jQuery and load the page into a specific section of
// my "master" html page.

```
$("#specificsection").load(url);
```

The loaded html shows unrecognized characters.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the meta tag does nothing.  You actually need to convert the encoding.

Check out this package:  https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite

Comment: At the risk of not sounding too bright, I do not see how to use that. Can you provide an example? I would use this with my jQuery .load() method?

Comment: @MikeCollins Not really because you didn't show us your existing code and this requires you to use Browserify to use in the browser.  So, you will have to load it with `require()` and then build your bundled JS.  From there, the example in the readme is pretty solid.  https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite#basic-api  If it were me, I'd just convert all your docs in a batch process ahead of time, and stop using Word to generate them.  It's going to be easier and won't require you to drop in 200KB of junk to load your content.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I put in an example. I've been at this too long and am starting to get too tired. Please see the example I put in the question.